Does Acts 15:18 constitute the end of the Amos 9:11-12 quote, or the beginning of James' response to it?
Acts 15:13-21 ESV translation:

13 After they finished speaking, James replied, “Brothers, listen to
me. 14 Simeon has related how God first visited the Gentiles, to take
from them a people for his name. 15 And with this the words of the
prophets agree, just as it is written,
16 “‘After this I will return, and I will rebuild the tent of David
that has fallen; I will rebuild its ruins, and I will restore it,
17 that the remnant of mankind may seek YHWH, and all the Gentiles
who are called by my name, declares YHWH, who makes these things
18 known from of old.’
19 Therefore my judgment is that we should not trouble those of the
Gentiles who turn to God, 20 but should write to them to abstain from
the things polluted by idols, and from sexual immorality, and from
what has been strangled, and from blood. 21 For from ancient
generations Moses has had in every city those who proclaim him, for he
is read every Sabbath in the synagogues.”

Acts 15:13-21 translation proposal with verse 18 starting the new sentence:

13 After they finished speaking, James replied, “Brothers, listen to me.
14 Simeon has related how God first visited the Gentiles, to take from
them a people for his name. 15 And with this the words of the prophets
agree, just as it is written,
16 “‘After this I will return, and I will rebuild the tent of David that
has fallen; I will rebuild its ruins, and I will restore it, 17 that the
remnant of mankind may seek YHWH, and all the Gentiles who are called
by my name, declares YHWH, who will do this.’
18 As this was known from ancient times, 19 it is my judgment, therefore, that we should not trouble those of the
Gentiles who turn to God, 20 but should write to them to abstain from the
things polluted by idols, and from sexual immorality, and from what
has been strangled, and from blood. 21 For from ancient generations Moses
has had in every city those who proclaim him, for he is read every
Sabbath in the synagogues.”

The grounds for making this proposal are that the quoted passage of Amos 9:11-12 concludes at "declares YHWH" without the anomalous extension. Even the LXX, which is quoted by James here in Acts 15, does not have the supposed extension.
This makes me wonder if the text in verse 18 forms the start of James' response following the Amos quote, which also does not have the verse 18 extension. The reason for this proposal is that it was in James' judgement that the Gentiles should not be troubled, because it was known since long ago that Moses' writings were read in every city on the Sabbath in the synagogues even to the Gentiles, who desired to join the Hebrews in circumcision and be grafted into Israel to inherit the promises of God.

Dottard is mistaken.
LXX: that the remnant of men, and all the Gentiles upon whom my name is called, may earnestly seek [me]

is not an "extension".

It's a different version of:
MT: that they may possess the remnant of Edom and all the nations that bear My name,”
LXX has read garash (seek) for yarash (possess). garash is translated by ἐκζητέω.
LXX has read edom (Edom) for adam (men)
Above all, "remnant, etc.etc" which in MT must be the object of the verb (because of object prefix et-), is in the LXX made nominative.
There is more, of which i am not certain. Of the above, I am certain.
See John Hunt's answer on Quora
Does the meaning of Amos 9:11-12 change significantly from the Hebrew Bible to the Septuagint and then to the quote in Acts 15:16-18?
As for the original question, γνωστὰ ἀπ᾽ αἰῶνος is not part of the quotation. I assume it was originally tauta gnwsta ap aiwnos, namely, "These things were known from ancient times" (by the prophets).
The quotation is a proof of what has come to pass, that God has called the Gentiles by His Name; as Paul had just been arguing.
In my opinion, this was pulled from an older text and the current author thought it to be part of the prophetic quotation.
poiwn tauta is difficult to make sense of anyway. And as the text would read tauta tauta, our author/redactor will have been confused, figured it was a scribal error and put it all together, omitting the 2nd tauta which should be the subject of the new sentence.

"See John Hunt's answer on Quora" — That item might change or go away at any time, and we'll not understand what this was supposed to mean. Instead, the relevant parts should be quoted (or perhaps summarized) explicitly within your answer and a citation link provided.

If it does, it does. This is a concise summary of my view expressed there, as relevant to the qn. It's disappointing to me that the only response is administrative not academic, but thx anyway.

It can often take some time before the right person reads an answer and is compelled to respond to it. This isn't a huge site in terms of the number of readers. ¶ I'm personally not  knowledgeable enough about the question to provide any meaningful response to the content. My comment was (as all comments are supposed to be) a suggestion as to how to improve the question. A well composed answer will receive more upvotes than one that isn't.

@hedgehogful - when you say that the current author "thought it to be part of the quotation", what did you mean by that?

@JoshuaB bc Acts 15.16-17 is a quote from Amos. The end does make sense but is confusing. I think v. 18 said: ταῦτα γνωστὰ ἀπ᾽ αἰῶνος. - which is commentary, not part  of the quote. Scribe / redactor misunderstood, esp as there's no punctuation, and v. 17 ends with the same word as v18 begins with - ταῦτα.    It may help to read the Quora article I wrote - it's less compressed. But I also included there links to the texts themselves. If you read the Bible texts first I think it will make sense.

@JoshuaB I just noticed the KJV adds a bit of text - to add the absent subject.  (KJV) Known [unto God are all his works] from the beginning of the world.   γνωστὰ ἀπ' αἰῶνος ἐστιν τῷ θεῷ πάντα τὰ ἔργα αὐτοῦ. (That may be what is confusing you, if you use the KJV.)  Plse follow the links from my Quora article to STEPbible. Judge for yourself.

This is actually quite simple - the LXX has a slightly extended text in Amos.  Let me set this out clearly:

Hebrew of Amos 9:11, 12 - “In that day I will restore the fallen tent
of David. I will repair its gaps, restore its ruins, and rebuild it as
in the days of old, that they may possess the remnant of Edom and all
the nations that bear My name,”


LXX of Amos 9:11, 12 - In that day I will raise up the tabernacle of David that is fallen, and will rebuild the ruins of it, and will
set up the parts thereof that have been broken down, and will build it
up as in the ancient days: that the remnant of men, and all the
Gentiles upon whom my name is called, may earnestly seek [me], saith
the Lord who does all these things.

Note the extra text in the LXX that is absent in the Hebrew.  It is now obvious that when James quoted the text of Amos 9:11, 12, he quoted from the LXX as recorded in Acts 15 and quoted by the OP.
Thus, the attribution as listed in most Bibles is correct and James' quote from Amos ends with Acts 15:17, 18.

Dottard, despite the LXX having a longer ending, it does not include the rendering of verse 18 in it's version of Amos 9:12. My original question stands: could the material in verse 18 make up the beginning of James' response?

@JoshuaB - No, the grammar of the text in Acts precludes this.  In any case, the text of the LXX we have now may not be the text of the LXX that James was quoting.  Further, NT writers often "adjusted" their quotes from the OT and rarely quote perfectly verbatim and often paraphrase.

@JoshuaB -you are persistent. Let the text say what it does rather than trying to force it to say what you want it to say

Dottard, I'm going to agree with you here. I think Acts 15:18 presents a now-lost LXX version rendering of the end of Amos 9:12.

I find it deeply frustrating that almost all of the New Testament quotes of the Old Testament are found in the LXX, and not the Masoretic text. Because of this, I find the LXX to be vastly superior to the MT, with the LXX representing an older vorlage of Hebrew than the Masoretic, to the tune of over 1000 years.

Joshua B.... Doesn't this leave out the DSS, which tend to agree with the Masoretic?

@DanFefferman, yes. The DSS is inferior to the LXX when it comes to the OT quotes that the apostles, even Christ himself, make in the NT.
